# Windows SCP gives weird response when trying to SCP files

Tags: linux, windows, scp

I have been researching this problem, but came up with nothing.

Whenever I wanna use the secure copy protocol:

```
scp -i $env:userprofile/.ssh/id_rsa -P my_port $env:userprofile/Desktop/test.txt matt@<linux_ip_address>:~/dir
```

And I get a:

```
TERM environment variable not set.
<assumed random characters>
```

Whenever I reinstalled my server and then to scp my public key it worked fine, but now it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any error messages when you ssh to matt@<linux_ip_address> ?

Comment: No i do not, only when i scp.

Comment: Take a look at initialization files (like $HOME/.profile on matt@<linux_ip_address>) to see if there are any commands related to TERM variable. And as a test, rename .profile to .profile.bak

Comment: Nothing like that, just PATHs